# advice needed pre-soldering bios chip

Tags: motherboard, bios, soldering

I managed to remove the dead bios chip from this Dell Motherboard, but it looks like I've managed to pull off the top layer of the board by mistake on some of the pins.  I have a replacement bios chip with a working bios programmed in and ready to solder back in place.  My question is, have I managed to fry this board permanently, or is there any chance soldering the new chip back on will work?  Is there anything I can/should do before attempting to solder new chip back on?
Thanks, Pingers

[image: bios chip on dell 1720 mobo]

Comment: That looks *really* bad. Looks like you ripped off the plating you usually solder on to.

Comment: Yipes, that's what I thought - I'll put this one down to experience - Cheers Journeyman

Comment: Lemme post that as an answer in more detail ;)

Comment: Depending how long the legs are on the new bios chip you might be able to straighten them enough to reach those resistors.

Comment: am a bit of a noob in this dept.  Tim, do you mean soldering the legs (if they reach) directly on to the resistors (these are presumably the parts north and south of the pads which link to the pads with green lines on pic?   I'm sure my phrasing of the question indicates my noobness in this arena.  I may as well have a go as i have nothing to lose, so any specific advice on how to attempt to put the chip back on very welcome :)

Comment: or could i "extend" the legs with solder?

Comment: The loss of pads makes it tricky. The only real way to do this would be to extend from the little SMT passives but you might desolder those as well by accident. Its fiddly work

Answer (score 1):

You kind of messed up the desoldering. Typically you solder pins onto metal plated contacts, and you desolder them from it. If you use too much or too little heat, the contacts are damaged. You've lost roughly half your solder pads.

In future, you'd want to add some *lower* temperature solder, and use a solder sucker/braid to get it off. Desoldering is one of those skills that needs a *ton* of practice to get right

In *theory* you may be able to replace these with fine jumper wires, especially if the trace lengths are not critical. That said, there's no real guarantee this will work reliably and soldering jumper wires in situations like this are somewhat advanced.